# why does this typedef struct to a function declaration compiles without errors?

Tags: c

clang and gcc compile this without warning

```
typedef struct {} Type(int test);
```

... and this too

```
typedef struct {} (*Type[256]);
```

this may or may not compile (because of the lack of type in the parameter)

```
typedef struct {} Type(test);
```

As far as I could tell, it is not possible to use these typedefs to declare variables.

Why these declarations are allowed? Do they have any purpose?

Comment: `typedef struct {} Type(int test);` is a type-alias of a function that takes one `int` argument and returns an empty anonymous structure. `typedef struct {} (*Type[256]);` is just `typedef struct {} *Type[256];`, which a type-alias for an array of 256 pointers to an anonymous and empty structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither Clang nor GCC uses the C standard by default. Allowing an empty structure is a GNU extension. To get closer to conformance with the C standard, using `-std=c18 -pedantic`. Then both GCC and Clang will produce diagnostic messages for the code in the question.

> As far as I could tell, it is not possible to use these typedefs to declare variables.

After `typedef struct {} Type(int test);`, `typedef *p;` declares `p` to be a pointer to the function of the described type.

After `typedef struct {} (*Type[256]);`, `Type p;` declares `p` to be an array of the described type.

> Why these declarations are allowed? Do they have any purpose?

They are a consequence of allowing anonymous structures. C has many things that are valid grammatically and semantically but do nothing, such as:

- `3+4;`
- `printf("");`
- `if (0) foo();`

Answer (score 0):

You can split it into:

```
typedef struct 
{
}struct_t;

typedef struct_t type(int test);

type myfuc; 

type *Type[256];
```

> As far as I could tell, it is not possible to use these typedefs to
> declare variables.

It is not the truth, I just declared variables type in the example above.

> Why these declarations are allowed? Do they have any purpose?

Yes they have. Example:

```
typedef int func(int, int b);

int Add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int Mul(int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}

int Invalid(int a, int b)
{
    return 0;
}


func *getFunc(char a)
{
    switch(a)
    {
        case 'a':
            return Add;
        case 'm':
            return Mul;
    }
    return Invalid;
}
```

Homework for you: try to write `getFunc` withoit those typedefs and see how weird syntax will be.